# python can read image file to binary

Tags: python, image, binary

i need to upload a image file, and i use MultipartPostHandler.py as people suggest.
but still doesn't work.
here is my code:

```
params = {"upload", open("12345.jpg", "rb")} // in 'rb'
opener = urllib2.build_opener(MultipartPostHandler)
res = opener.open(url, params)
```

and here is the code in MultipartPostHander:

```
def multipart_encode(vars, files, boundary = None, buffer = None):
    if boundary is None:
        boundary = mimetools.choose_boundary()
    if buffer is None:
        buffer = ''
    for(key, value) in vars:
        buffer += '--%s\r\n' % boundary
        buffer += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"' % key
        buffer += '\r\n\r\n' + value + '\r\n'
    for(key, fd) in files:
        file_size = os.fstat(fd.fileno())[stat.ST_SIZE]
        filename = fd.name.split('/')[-1]
        contenttype = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0] or 'application/octet-stream'
        buffer += '--%s\r\n' % boundary
        buffer += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"\r\n' % (key, filename)
        buffer += 'Content-Type: %s\r\n' % contenttype
        # buffer += 'Content-Length: %s\r\n' % file_size
        fd.seek(0)
        buffer += '\r\n' + fd.read() + '\r\n'
    buffer += '--%s--\r\n\r\n' % boundary
    return boundary, buffer
multipart_encode = Callable(multipart_encode)

https_request = http_request
```

and error appears at:

```
buffer += '\r\n' + fd.read() + '\r\n'
```

error is:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

this problem scrowed me a lot , please help me out! 
thx.

Comment: It's trying to append binary data to a string, but Python is trying to interpret that binary data as a string, and only allows valid ASCII characters in strings (bytes with values 0-127). Unfortunately I don't know how to append binary data to a string in Python, or I would have written an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: base64 encoding allows for a printable representation of binary data.  I'm not sure about the standard, but it couldn't hurt to try an encoding such as that.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but maybe you could use bytearray instead of str as a buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Doug Hellman's MultiPartForm class from his blog to upload files to our mail server sucessfully: http://pymotw.com/2/urllib2/index.html#module-urllib2

Hopefully you can use that as well.

Comment: Weird. I can upload any file I want with that script.

Answer (score 0):

[i think this can save me. aha.](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/178943)

`# convert every byte of data to the corresponding 2-digit hexadecimal`

`enter code here`hex_str = str(binascii.hexlify(data))`

`# now create a list of 2-digit hexadecimals`

`hex_list = []`

`bin_list = []`

`for ix in range(2, len(hex_str)-1, 2):`

```
    hex = hex_str[ix]+hex_str[ix+1]

    hex_list.append(hex)

    bin_list.append(bin(int(hex, 16))[2:])
```

`#print(bin_list)`

`bin_str = "".join(bin_list)`

`print(bin_str)`